# progress indicator bar

Tags: magento2, admin

I'm new in Magento, I want to ask how we make custom progress bar like this, I want to give feedback on user and display the percentage of process completion [image]

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps down below to use the UIKit progress bar on your Magento 2 project. The documentation for the component is here: [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction) Progress Bar https://getuikit.com/docs/progress.

Throughout these steps, I will assume that you are using a custom Magento 2 Module named `Company_MyModule`.

### 1. Download and install UIkit

Download the JS and CSS files from https://getuikit.com and place them under your Magento 2 custom module web directory:

- `app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/css` for the CSS
- `app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js` for the JS

### 2. Include the CSS

Include the CSS files in the `layout/default.xml` XML file (located in `app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`) as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Matrixmedia_Utility/css/uikit.min.css"/> <!-- UIKit main css file-->
        <css src="Matrixmedia_Utility/css/components/progress.min.css"/> <!-- UIKit Progress bar component css file-->        
    </head>
</page>
```

*NOTE: Make sure that the CSS files are properly included by inspecting your web page source code.*

### Include the JS

Create the file `requirejs-config.js` under `app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'uikit': 'Company_MyModule/js/uikit.min'
        },
        'config' : {
            'uikit' : {
                'base' : 'Company_MyModule/js'
            }
        }
    };
```

### Update your template

Create or update your PHTML file to implement the UIKit progress bar:

I assume that your PHTML template file name is `mytemplate.phtml` and that it is under `app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/`

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
 <div id="progressbar" class="uk-progress uk-progress-success">
      <div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery',  'uikit' ],
function( require, $, uikit ) {
            
   $(window).load(function () {             
                var bar = document.getElementById('progressbar');                                
                bar.max  = 5; // Total Steps
                bar.value  = 1; // completed Steps                
                var barmessage = $('.uk-progress-bar');                
                var percent = Math.floor(( bar.value  /  bar.max) * 100);
                barmessage.css('width', percent + '%').text(bar.value + ' out of '+bar.max+' Completed.');
                
                
                
                var animate = setInterval(function () {
                     bar.value += 1;
                     var percent = Math.floor(( bar.value  /  bar.max) * 100);
                     barmessage.css('width', percent + '%').text(bar.value + ' out of '+bar.max+' Completed.');
                     if (bar.value >= bar.max) {
                       clearInterval(animate);
                     }

                }, 1000);
     });                

    
});
</script>
```

#### NOTES:

1. You can change the values of the variables `bar.max` and `bar.value` to fit your requirements.
2. To demonstrate the UIKit progress bar, I used a timer with a set interval. You should use your event (like some Ajax Call ) to increase the progress bar value.

[image]

Comment: actually I need to add the progress bar in admin side, can we do that? I see the documentation in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/pattern-library/feedbackToUser/progressIndicator/progressIndicator.html, by default progress indicator in magento admin page is spinner but in my case my function need at least 5 minutes to executed, so i think it is better to change the spinner into progress bar, it is possible? thank you

Comment: hello, @Pritam, how can we show the count instead of percentage?Also i didn't find this file components/progress.min.css